# SSIS OLEDB Source - only wrong Codepage works

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'am using an OLEDB-Source with the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 as the provider to read strings from an SQL Server Table.

The Database uses the Codepage 850. SSIS only maps the characters right, if I select Codepage 1252 in the OLEDB Source.

Database Collation with corresponding Codepage 850:
[image]

How could this happen and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Larnu see my edits, then you know why.

Comment: @Larnu if you think the data is stored under a different Codepage, I could provide some varchar rows with the corresponding hex values.